# Build works in RStudio, on travis, but not through devtools::install_github

Tags: r, devtools

I have a package on a branch of a [github repository](https://github.com/HughParsonage/grattan/tree/CRAN-2016). The build appears to succeed on Travis-CI, as well as when I hit 'Build & Reload' in RStudio. However, when I `install_github`, I get the error message:

> Error: running command '"C:/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC' had status 2

The particular command is:

```
devtools::install_github("hughparsonage/grattan", ref = "CRAN-2016")
```

`sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] grattan_0.4.0.1        microbenchmark_1.4-2.1 testthat_1.0.2         devtools_1.12.0       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7      assertthat_0.1   dplyr_0.5.0      digest_0.6.10    crayon_1.3.2     withr_1.0.2      chron_2.3-47     grid_3.3.1       R6_2.2.0        
[10] plyr_1.8.4       DBI_0.5-1        gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.0     ggplot2_2.1.0    data.table_1.9.6 tools_3.3.1      munsell_0.4.3   
[19] rsconnect_0.5    colorspace_1.2-7 memoise_1.0.0    tibble_1.2
```

Comment: works for me on Ubuntu 14.04.  Do you have the development tools installed properly where R can find them (`devtools::find_rtools()`)?  Does the branch matter, i.e. can you install the same stuff successfully from the master branch/ without `ref` ?

Comment: Well this is odd. I get the same error when I run `find_rtools()`. It is installed on my computer, however.

Comment: And now running just `devtools::install_github("hughparsonage/grattan")` fails with the same error.

Comment: I've lodged an issue on github. https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1386

Comment: based on a conversation [elsewhere](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/182) I'm guessing that some R infrastructure may be out of sync due to recent release of R 3.3.2 ... ? results of `sessionInfo()` would be useful too ...

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker I've edited the q to provide `sessionInfo()`.